# Grabbing all results for a certain query Yelp API using Python

Tags: python

Sorry I'm a noobie with Python, I apologize that this question is extremely vague... Essentially, what I want to do is get a list of all bars in certain cities (ie Toronto, San Francisco, etc). I have used this https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/python but this only grabs the top result from the queried list. How would I manipulate this to grab all results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [code that actually runs the search for you](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/python/sample.py#L115)

```
businesses = response.get('businesses')

if not businesses:
    print u'No businesses for {0} in {1} found.'.format(term, location)
    return

business_id = businesses[0]['id']
```

It's the last line that's limiting the result to just the first (`[0]`) result. If you loop over the entire `businesses` variable you will get the full list instead. You will either need to modify the code where it's installed on your machine or just download that file and modify it in-place. For Python scripts like that, the lines

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

are what runs when you run `python sample.py` at the command line. Modify the function `main()` or the functions it calls to modify the behavior you get.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a great answer and I know what to do now :)

Comment: Got it, thanks Tom! Just another quick question - it appears that i can only do SEARCH_LIMIT = 20, if I do a larger number, I get "Encountered HTTP error 400. Abort program.". Do you know why this is?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a limitation of the free API tier. It doesn't say [explicitly in the docs](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api) but it looks like 20 is the magic number. You can get at least 20 more results by setting an offset parameter to page through results. Make sure to handle the case where you get 0 results back.